# Logout doesn't revoke tokens in OneLogin OpenId Connect

Tags: api, authentication, session, token, onelogin

I'm trying to use https://developers.onelogin.com/openid-connect/api/logout to log out of my session and the API documentations say that it will also revoke all tokens. However, when I call the /introspection endpoint with my access_token it returns that it is still active.  I'm following the specifications on the API docs. I have tried making the GET call just to the endpoint without and additional params and including the id_token_hint.  For both cases, I get a 200 response and am redirected, but the token doesn't get revoked.  Am I missing any steps here?

Comment: It maybe shortcoming of OneLogin APIs. Better to revoke tokens once logout. You can also open their support ticket. Their support is very active and responsive.

Comment: You can also check if you have given "true" as value for "logout" request parameter